# Spark streaming with Kafka connector stopping

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am beginning using Spark streaming. I want to get a stream from Kafka with a sample code I found on the Spark documentation : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

Here is my code :

```
object SparkStreaming {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test_kafka_spark").setMaster("local[*]") // local parallelism 1
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))

    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9093",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "test",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )

    val topics = Array("spark")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )

    stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value))

  }
}
```

All seemed to start well at but the job stopped immediately, logs as follow :

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
17/04/19 14:37:37 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/04/19 14:37:37 WARN Utils: Your hostname, thibaut-Precision-M4600 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.192.176.101 instead (on interface eno1)
17/04/19 14:37:37 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: thibaut
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: thibaut
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(thibaut); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(thibaut); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 41046.
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-266e2f13-0eb2-40a8-9d2f-d50797099a29
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 879.3 MB
17/04/19 14:37:37 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.192.176.101:4040
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 39207.
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.192.176.101:39207
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.192.176.101, 39207, None)
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.192.176.101:39207 with 879.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.192.176.101, 39207, None)
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.192.176.101, 39207, None)
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.192.176.101, 39207, None)
17/04/19 14:37:38 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding enable.auto.commit to false for executor
17/04/19 14:37:38 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding auto.offset.reset to none for executor
17/04/19 14:37:38 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding executor group.id to spark-executor-test
17/04/19 14:37:38 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding receive.buffer.bytes to 65536 see KAFKA-3135
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.192.176.101:4040
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/04/19 14:37:38 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-f28a1361-58ba-416b-ac8e-11da0044c1f2
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you haven't started your StreamingContext. 
Try adding these 2 lines at the end

```
ssc.start
ssc.awaitTermination
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not call any action on DStream, so nothing gets executed (map is a transformation and is lazy), also you need to start the StreamingContext.

Please look into this complete example.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/DirectKafkaWordCount.scala